# Prepend to regex match

Tags: linux, bash

I got a variable in a bash script that I need to replace.  The only constant in the line is that it will be ending in "_(*x)xxxp.mov".  Where x's are numbers and can be of either 3 or 4 of length.  For example, I know how to replace the value but only if it is a constant:

```
echo 'whiteout-tlr1_1080p.mov' | sed 's/_[0-9]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]p.mov/_h1080p.mov/g'
```

How can I carry over the regex match to replacement line?

*Edit:*

Ok I just learned that grep can print only the match would it better to to do something like this?

```
urltrail=$(echo $@ | grep -o [0-9]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]p.mov)
newurl=$(sed 's/$urltrail/h$urltrail/g')
```

Hmm, tried the above but am getting a hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Back Reference](http://www.google.com/search?q=backreference+regular+expression)

```
sed 's/_\([0-9]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)p.mov/_h\1p.mov/g'
```

The back-reference `\n`,  where `n` is a single digit, matches the substring previously matched by the `n`th parenthesized subexpression of the regular expression.

Comment: Well put Ian.  Good to learn about sed and regex's and what they can do.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not piping the old path into sed, so sed is hanging waiting for input.

```
newurl=$(echo $@ |sed 's/$urltrail/h$urltrail/g')
```

Comment: This will search for the literal text 'urltrail' anchored after the end of the line.  You could use double quotes and do sed "s/$urltrail...", but that opens a whole different can of worms (eg, if $urltrail contains spaces or '/' or other regex meta-charactes.)